# How to show Review Form instead of Review tab in product detail page magento2?

Tags: magento2.2.3, magento2.3.0, magento2.2.8, magento2.2.9

I want to show review form after the related products section instead of Review tab on Product Detail Page in magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override this **catalog_product_view.xml** file via current theme with path:
**app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

and add below code inside **catalog_product_view.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <move element="reviews.tab" destination="content" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you had already override this **catalog_product_view.xml** file, then you need to add below single line code only inside the body tag:

```
 <move element="reviews.tab" destination="content" after="-"/>
```

Hope this solution will help you!

Comment: It's working brother, Thank you!!!!